# Почему возникла ошибка "New transaction is not allowed"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Столкнулся с ошибкой

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

несколько часов не мог найти причину. Есть метод репозитория, вкратце делающий следующее (да, лишняя логика на уровне репозитория):

```
return
    rc.Context.Chats.Include("Participants.User")
        .Where(m => m.Participants.Any(u => u.User.ID == userId))
        .Each(
            c =>
                c.Name = String.Join(", ", 
                            c.Participants.Where(u => u.User.ID != userId).Select(s => s.User.Login)))
        .ToList();
```

Метод использует самопальное расширение `Each`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs, Action<T> action)
{
    if (xs != null)
        xs.Each((i, x) => action(x));

    return xs;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs, Action<int, T> action)
{
    var e = xs.GetEnumerator();
    for (int i = 0; e.MoveNext(); i++)
    {
        action(i, e.Current);
    }
    return xs;
}
```

Если после вызова метода репозитория делать любые действия с контекстом выскакивает вышеозначенная ошибка. В поисках решения я добавил один дополнительный `.ToList()` после `Where` - и вуаля - всё заработало.

```
return
    rc.Context.Chats.Include("Participants.User")
        .Where(m => m.Participants.Any(u => u.User.ID == userId))
        .ToList()
        .Each(
            c =>
                c.Name = String.Join(", ", 
                            c.Participants.Where(u => u.User.ID != userId).Select(s => s.User.Login)))
        .ToList();
```

Однако, я пока не могу понять причину такого поведения. Почему при прямом вызове конвертации `ToList()` поток закрывает транзакцию - а при приведении `IQueryable` к `IEnumerable`, последующей работе с ним и приведением `ToList()` - нет?

Comment: Ваш `.Each` и его использование ужасно. В первом случае вы пробегаете последовательность, получаете элементы, выбрасываете их, и отдаёте наружу последовательность, которая при перечислении снова вытащит свежие элементы из базы. Во втором случае по случайности у вас последовательность, скармливаемая `.Each`, материальна, и ваш код работает. Мой совет — **никогда** не смешивайте чистые функции LINQ и код с побочными эффектами, это никогда не работает как задумано.

Comment: Уберите `.Each` и перепишите код на `Select`.

Comment: А по поводу вопроса — судя по всему, проблема в висящих объектах, которые создаёт `.Each` в первом случае.

Comment: (Чистые функции в смысле pure, конечно.)

Comment: @VladD, можете пояснить немного про "висящие объекты"? Каким именно образом код их создает в данном случае?

Comment: Ну, вы в `Each<T>` пробегаетесь по списку. Если список не пропущен через `ToList`, это прямой запрос в базу. То есть, для энумерации читается база, и создаются объекты. Когда вы выдаёте наружу из этой функции назад `IEnumerable<T>`, снаружи происходит на нём `ToList()`, и данные из базы читаются повторно. Как-то так.

Answer (score 1):

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Ошибка мне подсказывает, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к rc.Context одновременно из двух потоков. Да и ваш код это подтверждает (rc.Context). DbContext нужно создавать при каждом запросе. То есть на транзакцию. Он реализует паттерн "единица работы".

```
using(var context = new DbContext())
{
   // ваши манипуляции с базой.
}
```

rc должен не содержать поле Context, а должен выступать в роли фабрику тогда:

```
using(var context = rc.CreateContext())
{
   // ваши манипуляции с базой.
}
```

Если нет, попробуйте сделать так:

```
return rc.Context.Chats.Include("Participants.User")
    .Where(m => m.Participants.Any(u => u.User.ID == userId))
    .ToList()
    .Select(c =>
    {
       c.Name = String.Join(", ", c.Participants
                                   .Where(u => u.User.ID != userId)
                                   .Select(s => s.User.Login));
       return c;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: В реальном коде rc выступает как результат работы фабрики. Я опустил подробности создания контекста как несущественные в данном случае (указал, что код приведен "вкратце"). Время жизни контекста здесь не важно для данной ошибки. Кроме того, ваш код в последнем случае не эквивалентен приведенному мной.

Comment: Мой .Select эквивалентен вашему .Each, но я ошибся в другом. Подобный .Select невозможно преобразовать в лямду. и перед его вызовом в любом случае нужно вызвать .ToList()